# Show that $\sup f(x) \leq \inf g(y)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: D \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: D\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be functions ($D$ nonempty). Suppose that $f(x) \leq g(y)$ for all $x\in D$ and $y \in D$. Show that

$$\sup f(x) \leq \inf g(y)$$

> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \mbox{Given } f(x) & \leq & g(y) \mbox{ for all } x,y \in D\\
> \Rightarrow \sup_{x \in D} f(x) & \leq & g(y)\\
> \Rightarrow \sup_{x \in D} f(x) & \leq & \inf_{y \in D} g(y)\\
> \end{eqnarray*} 
>   Now $y$ and $x$ are just dummy variables, so in the last step replace $y$ by $x$. And we have : $$ \sup_{x \in D} f(x) \leq  \inf_{x \in D} g(x). $$

Is correct the solution? Or can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is correct. Maybe it is better to understand if you fix values. Like this:

> Fix $y_0\in D$. Since $f(x)\leq g(y)$ for all $x,y\in D$, it follows that
>   $$f(x)\leq g(y_0),\ \forall x\in D\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sup_{x\in D} f(x) \leq f(y_0).$$
>   Since $y_0$ was fixed arbitrarily, we have that
>   $$\sup_{x\in D} f(x) \leq f(y),\ \forall y\in D\ \ \Rightarrow\ \  \sup_{x\in D} f(x) \leq \sup_{y\in D} f(y).$$